# Why Python's re module escapes semicolon characters

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Why Python's re module escapes semicolon characters?

```
print(re.escape('text;text'))
```

gives me the following output:

```
text\;text
```

Comment: because it consider `;` as a special character.

Comment: Because the escape routine is very simple: it escapes *all non-alphanumeric characters*.

Comment: What did you expect instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> re.escape.__doc__
'Escape all non-alphanumeric characters in pattern.'
```

It escapes `;`(*semicolon*), because `;` is not an alphanumeric character.

Answer (score 4):

It escapes a semicolon because that is what it's designed to do. As per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape), it escapes all non-alphanumeric characters.

> Return string with all non-alphanumerics backslashed; this is useful if you want to match an arbitrary literal string that may have regular expression metacharacters in it.